# Laptop keyboard is randomly executing all buttons

Tags: windows-8, laptop, keyboard

My laptop just randomly starts entering weird things. Like when I am just typing something, my keyboard is just typing randomly like 5 letters/numbers/symbols while I am typing. It even executed the F5 automatically out of no where. The keyboard is even executing it while I'm not typing. When the laptop is executing the buttons, and it's done, I cant type anything for like 5 seconds after. What's the problem? Is it the hardware? What should I do?

Comment: Have you scanned your system for malwares? Try using the on screen keyboard or a usb keyboard and see if it exhibits the same.

Comment: @miggy Is there anyway to deactive the keyboard for the laptop?

Comment: Not sure if there are any other ways, but to deactivate a laptop's keyboard, you have to disconnect it from its connector on the motherboard.

Comment: @miggy Well I have been typing with a usb keyboard and I am not getting random letters etc. So the problem is the laptop keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using a usb keyboard without problem, most probably the laptop keyboard is defective and needs to be replaced.